# Material-ui : SvgIcon issues with some paths

Tags: svg, material-ui, render

I would like to use [SvgIcon](https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/#svgicon-api) like that :

```
const iconsSVG = {
    // WORKING
    "PS1": "M8.985 2.596v17.548l3.915 1.261V6.688c0-.69.304-1.151.794-.991.636.181.76.814.76 1.505v5.876c2.441 1.193 4.362-.002 4.362-3.153 0-3.237-1.126-4.675-4.438-5.827-1.307-.448-3.728-1.186-5.391-1.502h-.002zm4.656 16.242l6.296-2.275c.715-.258.826-.625.246-.818-.586-.192-1.637-.139-2.357.123l-4.205 1.499v-2.385l.24-.085s1.201-.42 2.913-.615c1.696-.18 3.785.029 5.437.661 1.848.601 2.041 1.472 1.576 2.072s-1.622 1.036-1.622 1.036l-8.544 3.107v-2.297l.02-.023zM1.808 18.6c-1.9-.545-2.214-1.668-1.352-2.321.801-.585 2.159-1.051 2.159-1.051l5.616-2.013v2.313L4.206 17c-.705.271-.825.632-.239.826.586.195 1.637.15 2.343-.12L8.248 17v2.074c-.121.029-.256.044-.391.073-1.938.331-3.995.196-6.037-.479l-.012-.068z",
    "PS2": "M7.46 13.779v.292h4.142v-3.85h3.796V9.93h-4.115v3.85zm16.248-3.558v1.62h-7.195v2.23H24v-.292h-7.168v-1.646H24V9.929h-7.487v.292zm-16.513 0v1.62H0v2.23h.292v-1.938H7.46V9.929H0v.292Z",
    "PS3": "M15.363 9.438h-3.148c-.97 0-1.447.6-1.447 1.38v2.366c0 .483-.228.83-.71.83H7.304c-.02 0-.035.017-.035.035v.47c0 .02.01.032.03.032h3.11c.97 0 1.45-.597 1.45-1.377V10.81c0-.484.225-.832.71-.832h2.782c.02 0 .04-.014.04-.033V9.47c0-.02-.02-.035-.04-.035zm-9.267 0H.038c-.022 0-.038.017-.038.035v.477c0 .02.016.036.038.036h5.694c.48 0 .71.347.71.83s-.228.83-.71.83H1.228c-.7 0-1.227.587-1.227 1.366v1.513c0 .02.02.037.04.037h1.03c.02 0 .04-.016.04-.037v-1.513c0-.48.28-.82.68-.82H6.1c.97 0 1.444-.595 1.444-1.375 0-.778-.473-1.38-1.442-1.38zm17.454 2.498c-.015-.015-.015-.04 0-.056.3-.25.45-.627.45-1.062 0-.778-.474-1.38-1.446-1.38h-6.057c-.02 0-.036.018-.036.038v.475c0 .02.02.04.04.04h5.7c.48 0 .715.35.715.83s-.23.83-.712.83h-5.7c-.02 0-.036.02-.036.04v.48c0 .02.016.034.037.034h5.7c.63.007.71.62.71.93v.06c0 .485-.23.833-.71.833h-5.7c-.02 0-.036.015-.036.034v.477c0 .02.015.037.036.037h6.05c.973 0 1.446-.645 1.446-1.38v-.057c0-.47-.15-.916-.45-1.19z",
    // NOT WORKING
    "PSP": "M67.5,194 174.4,194 174.4,225.7 71.7,225.7 71.7,253.2 67.5,253.2 67.5,221.5 170.2,221.5 170.2,198.2 67.5,198.2 67.5,194 M307.9,225.7 307.9,253.2 303.7,253.2 303.7,221.5 406.3,221.5 406.3,198.2 303.7,198.2 303.7,194 410.6,194 410.6,225.7 307.9,225.7 M228.9,194 228.9,249 174.4,249 174.4,253.2 233.3,253.2 233.3,198.2 287.8,198.2 287.8,194 228.9,194",
    "PC": "M1210 2030 l0 -1730 420 0 420 0 2 583 3 582 245 3 245 2 268 268 267 267 0 605 0 605 -273 273 -272 272 -663 0 -662 0 0 -1730z m998 571 l2 -462 -77 3 -78 3 -3 457 -2 457 67 3 c38 2 73 3 78 3 6 -1 11 -165 13 -464z M3492 3487 l-272 -272 0 -1190 0 -1190 268 -268 268 -267 450 0 449 0 268 268 267 267 -2 475 -3 475 -440 0 -440 0 -3 -397 -2 -398 -70 0 -70 0 0 1035 0 1035 70 0 70 0 2 -327 3 -328 440 0 440 0 3 405 2 405 -272 272 -273 273 -440 0 -440 0 -273 -273z"
}

// ... some piece of code latter

<SvgIcon>
   <path d={iconsSVG["PS3"]} /> // any key of the iconsSVG could be used
</SvgIcon>
```

However, the "PSP" and "PC" icons aren't displayed and I cannot find out what could be the error when I convert them.
Here are the original files :

**PSP icon :**

```html
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
    
        <path d="M 67.5,194 174.4,194 174.4,225.7 71.7,225.7 71.7,253.2 67.5,253.2 67.5,221.5 170.2,221.5    170.2,198.2 67.5,198.2 67.5,194"></path>
        <path d="M 307.9,225.7 307.9,253.2 303.7,253.2 303.7,221.5 406.3,221.5 406.3,198.2 303.7,198.2 303.7,194 410.6,194 410.6,225.7 307.9,225.7"></path>
        <path d="M 228.9,194 228.9,249 174.4,249 174.4,253.2 233.3,253.2 233.3,198.2 287.8,198.2 287.8,194    228.9,194"></path>
    </svg>
```

**PC icon :**

```html
 <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="640.000000pt" height="407.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 640.000000 407.000000"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,407.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
    fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M1210 2030 l0 -1730 420 0 420 0 2 583 3 582 245 3 245 2 268 268
    267 267 0 605 0 605 -273 273 -272 272 -663 0 -662 0 0 -1730z m998 571 l2
    -462 -77 3 -78 3 -3 457 -2 457 67 3 c38 2 73 3 78 3 6 -1 11 -165 13 -464z"/>
    <path d="M3492 3487 l-272 -272 0 -1190 0 -1190 268 -268 268 -267 450 0 449
    0 268 268 267 267 -2 475 -3 475 -440 0 -440 0 -3 -397 -2 -398 -70 0 -70 0 0
    1035 0 1035 70 0 70 0 2 -327 3 -328 440 0 440 0 3 405 2 405 -272 272 -273
    273 -440 0 -440 0 -273 -273z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Look at the magnitude of the values. The numbers are much bigger i.e. too big in the non-working versions.

Comment: So any idea of tools I should use for that conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSP and PC icons have 3 and 2 path and viewBox="0 0 500 500" viewBox="0 0 640.000000 407.000000"
This SvgIcon has 1 path and "0 0 24 24" default viewBox

You can specify viewBox prop and path array for your icons but in PC item there is also g tag so it won't be displayed that way

```
const iconsSVG = {
  // WORKING
  PS1: {
    path: [
      "M8.985 2.596v17.548l3.915 1.261V6.688c0-.69.304-1.151.794-.991.636.181.76.814.76 1.505v5.876c2.441 1.193 4.362-.002 4.362-3.153 0-3.237-1.126-4.675-4.438-5.827-1.307-.448-3.728-1.186-5.391-1.502h-.002zm4.656 16.242l6.296-2.275c.715-.258.826-.625.246-.818-.586-.192-1.637-.139-2.357.123l-4.205 1.499v-2.385l.24-.085s1.201-.42 2.913-.615c1.696-.18 3.785.029 5.437.661 1.848.601 2.041 1.472 1.576 2.072s-1.622 1.036-1.622 1.036l-8.544 3.107v-2.297l.02-.023zM1.808 18.6c-1.9-.545-2.214-1.668-1.352-2.321.801-.585 2.159-1.051 2.159-1.051l5.616-2.013v2.313L4.206 17c-.705.271-.825.632-.239.826.586.195 1.637.15 2.343-.12L8.248 17v2.074c-.121.029-.256.044-.391.073-1.938.331-3.995.196-6.037-.479l-.012-.068z",
    ],
    viewBox: "0 0 24 24",
  },
  PS2: {
    path: [
      "M7.46 13.779v.292h4.142v-3.85h3.796V9.93h-4.115v3.85zm16.248-3.558v1.62h-7.195v2.23H24v-.292h-7.168v-1.646H24V9.929h-7.487v.292zm-16.513 0v1.62H0v2.23h.292v-1.938H7.46V9.929H0v.292Z",
    ],
    viewBox: "0 0 24 24",
  },
  PS3: {
    path: [
      "M15.363 9.438h-3.148c-.97 0-1.447.6-1.447 1.38v2.366c0 .483-.228.83-.71.83H7.304c-.02 0-.035.017-.035.035v.47c0 .02.01.032.03.032h3.11c.97 0 1.45-.597 1.45-1.377V10.81c0-.484.225-.832.71-.832h2.782c.02 0 .04-.014.04-.033V9.47c0-.02-.02-.035-.04-.035zm-9.267 0H.038c-.022 0-.038.017-.038.035v.477c0 .02.016.036.038.036h5.694c.48 0 .71.347.71.83s-.228.83-.71.83H1.228c-.7 0-1.227.587-1.227 1.366v1.513c0 .02.02.037.04.037h1.03c.02 0 .04-.016.04-.037v-1.513c0-.48.28-.82.68-.82H6.1c.97 0 1.444-.595 1.444-1.375 0-.778-.473-1.38-1.442-1.38zm17.454 2.498c-.015-.015-.015-.04 0-.056.3-.25.45-.627.45-1.062 0-.778-.474-1.38-1.446-1.38h-6.057c-.02 0-.036.018-.036.038v.475c0 .02.02.04.04.04h5.7c.48 0 .715.35.715.83s-.23.83-.712.83h-5.7c-.02 0-.036.02-.036.04v.48c0 .02.016.034.037.034h5.7c.63.007.71.62.71.93v.06c0 .485-.23.833-.71.833h-5.7c-.02 0-.036.015-.036.034v.477c0 .02.015.037.036.037h6.05c.973 0 1.446-.645 1.446-1.38v-.057c0-.47-.15-.916-.45-1.19z",
    ],
    viewBox: "0 0 24 24",
  },
  // NOT WORKING
  PSP: {
    path: [
      "M 67.5,194 174.4,194 174.4,225.7 71.7,225.7 71.7,253.2 67.5,253.2 67.5,221.5 170.2,221.5 170.2,198.2 67.5,198.2 67.5,194",
      "M 307.9,225.7 307.9,253.2 303.7,253.2 303.7,221.5 406.3,221.5 406.3,198.2 303.7,198.2 303.7,194 410.6,194 410.6,225.7 307.9,225.7",
      "M 228.9,194 228.9,249 174.4,249 174.4,253.2 233.3,253.2 233.3,198.2 287.8,198.2 287.8,194    228.9,194",
    ],
    viewBox: "0 0 500 500",
  },
  PC: {
    path: [
      "M1210 2030 l0 -1730 420 0 420 0 2 583 3 582 245 3 245 2 268 268 267 267 0 605 0 605 -273 273 -272 272 -663 0 -662 0 0 -1730z m998 571 l2 -462 -77 3 -78 3 -3 457 -2 457 67 3 c38 2 73 3 78 3 6 -1 11 -165 13 -464z",
      "M3492 3487 l-272 -272 0 -1190 0 -1190 268 -268 268 -267 450 0 449 0 268 268 267 267 -2 475 -3 475 -440 0 -440 0 -3 -397 -2 -398 -70 0 -70 0 01035 0 1035 70 0 70 0 2 -327 3 -328 440 0 440 0 3 405 2 405 -272 272 -273 273 -440 0 -440 0 -273 -273z",
    ],
    viewBox: "0 0 640.000000 407.000000",
  },
};

// ... some piece of code latter

function App() {
  const type = "PC";
  const { viewBox, path } = iconsSVG[type];
  return (
    <SvgIcon viewBox={viewBox}>
      {path.map((d) => (
        <path d={d} key={d} />
      ))}
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

You should better save your SVG as simple react components without material SVG then import them and put to an array

your PC file svg code

```
import React from "react";

export const PCSvg = () => (
  <svg
      width='24'
      height='24'
    viewBox="0 0 640.000000 407.000000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  >
    <g
      transform="translate(0.000000,407.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
      fill="#000000"
      stroke="none"
    >
      <path
        d="M1210 2030 l0 -1730 420 0 420 0 2 583 3 582 245 3 245 2 268 268
267 267 0 605 0 605 -273 273 -272 272 -663 0 -662 0 0 -1730z m998 571 l2
-462 -77 3 -78 3 -3 457 -2 457 67 3 c38 2 73 3 78 3 6 -1 11 -165 13 -464z"
      />
      <path
        d="M3492 3487 l-272 -272 0 -1190 0 -1190 268 -268 268 -267 450 0 449
0 268 268 267 267 -2 475 -3 475 -440 0 -440 0 -3 -397 -2 -398 -70 0 -70 0 0
1035 0 1035 70 0 70 0 2 -327 3 -328 440 0 440 0 3 405 2 405 -272 272 -273
273 -440 0 -440 0 -273 -273z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
);
```

Your import code

```
import { PCSvg } from './PC';

function App() {
 
  return (
      <PCSvg />
  );
}

export default App;
```